# how to execute command using php

Tags: php, command, execute

I want to execute some command using php, like `exec()` function or `system()` function.

But the default `cmd.exe` was denied. There is another cmd.exe in 'E:\web\', I want to execute command   using 'E:\web\cmd.exe',what should I use `exec()` function or `system()` function?

Comment: Please, show your code. Also what permissions are on that executable file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  guess it's  “php.exe”  that  you  should use.

LIKE:

1. open windows  console
2. XXX> /PATH_TO_YOUR_PHP_BIN/php   /PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT_FILE/somescript.php

you can set your PHP_BIN_PATH  as environment variable for convenience,